# Android media controller shows display for a short time

Tags: android, mediacontroller

This below activity works fine but the mediaController display only if I click on the screen. And the second problem is the media controller display only for 3 sec. what should I do to remove this problem?

```
public class PlayingActivity extends Activity
{

    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private EditText mPath;
    MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playingactivity);
        mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
        mPath.setText(GlobalVariable.getstrEmail());
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/download/test.mp3");
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.findFocus();
        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
        mediaController.show(0);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you want? The mediaController is always displayed on the screen?

Comment: yes i want it always upto mp3 file finish

Comment: There is a note from Android Develop doc: public void show (int timeout) I remembered I can use "show(0)" successfully in android 1.5. I just try it in android 2.3, the result is same with you. I don't understand this case. Maybe you can set the duration of the mp3 to the mediaController timeout.


Show the controller on screen. It will go away automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
Parameters

timeout The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show the controller until hide() is called.

Answer (score 19):

```
mediaController.requestFocus();
```

will make it display as soon as the video starts ( without requiring the click)

and

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaController.show(0);
            }
        });
```

Will keep it on the screen. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Requesting focus or specifying 0 in show method never worked for me.

The problem is that MediaController class has default timeout of 3000ms or 3seconds. And its show() method replaces our given parameter to its default parameter. Its a stupid bug resulting from untested code at Google.

We need to implement a lousy workaround of replacing the default value by desired value.

Try the below code. It should work.

```
mediaControls = new MediaController(getActivity()){
        @Override
        public void show (int timeout){
            if(timeout == 3000) timeout = 20000; //Set to desired number
            super.show(timeout);
        }
    };
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
```

Answer (score 1):

Neo's suggestions are perfect. But I would like to add "mp.start()" to onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) method, without which the media file won't start playing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problem in MediaController:

1. auto hide is 3s by default
2. Tapping on the video shows/hide the control bar

For the first part it's easly fixed changing the default timeout value of start to zero (zero means indefinite,it is used internally as the video starts) like this:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this){
            @Override
            public void show() {
                super.show(0);//Default no auto hide timeout
            }
    };
```

The second problem is a little tricky because the click handler is declared as private and final so we do not have any control on that.
My solution is to use another function to set visibility and disable the hide function like this:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this){

            @Override
            public void show() {
                super.show(0);//Default no auto hide timeout
            }
            @Override
            public void hide() {
                   //DOES NOTHING
            }

            void setVisible(boolean visible){//USE THIS FUNCTION INSTEAD
                if(visible)
                    super.show();
                else
                    super.hide();
            }
    };
```

You can also add a variable to re-enable standard functionality if visibility is set to false like so:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this){
                private boolean forceVisible=false;

                @Override
                public void show() {
                    super.show(0);//Default no auto hide timeout
                }
                @Override
                public void hide() {
                    if(!forceVisible)super.hide();
                }

                void setVisible(boolean visible){
                    forceVisible=visible;
                    if(visible)
                        super.show();
                    else
                        super.hide();
                }
        };
```